# How to avoid instanceof when working to fill in varying ArrayLists and table models?

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am looking for a way to improve the following method or to find out if this is the best way to do it. I have a superclass called Product and then I have Yoghurt, Crisp, etc. extending it. My Lists are declared as private static ArrayList inside of the class where this method is being executed, my main client class. I am trying to add the object to the correct list but don't know of a better way to do this. Am I going about it the long winded way or is this acceptable?

```
public <T> void addToTable(T obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Yoghurt) {
            yoghurtList.add((Yoghurt)obj);
            yoghurtList.sort(new IdSorter());
            yoghurtModel.fireInsert();    //this method just does fireTableDataChanged()
        } else if (obj instanceof Crisp) {
            crispList.add((Crisp)obj);
            crispList.sort(new IdSorter());
            crispModel.fireInsert();
        } else if (obj instanceof Milk) {
            milkList.add((Milk)obj);
            milkList.sort(new IdSorter());
            milkModel.fireInsert();
        } else if (obj instanceof Drink) {
            drinkList.add((Drink)obj);
            drinkList.sort(new IdSorter());
            drinkModel.fireInsert();
        } else if (obj instanceof Bar) {
            barList.add((Bar)obj);
            barList.sort(new IdSorter());
            barModel.fireInsert();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really don't have enough code/context for a proper code review, and the code you provided won't even compile (unmatched parenthesis: `crispList.add(Crisp)obj);`), but it seems like what you are looking for is a mapping from class to model, something like: `HashMap<Class<T>,Model<T>> class_to_model`, which you could use like: `Model<T> model = class_to_model.get(o.getClass()); model.getList().add(obj); model.fireInsert();`

Comment: Your title should state what your code does. Check the relevant Help pages.